# Delete the element of the list if the number is between 750 and 850

Tags: r, for-loop

want to solve using for loop

```
x = list(20000,45,443,"Texas",680,410,"Chennai",121,799,190,810) 

 `  for (i in seq(x)){
  if(x[[i]]>750 & x[[i]]<850){
    x[[i]] <- NA }}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) !(is.numeric(x) & x > 750 & x < 850), num_list)

#[[1]]
#[1] 20000

#[[2]]
#[1] 45

#[[3]]
#[1] 443

#[[4]]
#[1] "Texas"

#[[5]]
#[1] 680

#[[6]]
#[1] 410

#[[7]]
#[1] "Chennai"

#[[8]]
#[1] 121

#[[9]]
#[1] 190
```

and here are some more variations of the same logic.

```
num_list[sapply(num_list, function(x) !(is.numeric(x) & x > 750 & x < 850))]
purrr::discard(num_list, ~is.numeric(.x) & .x > 750 & .x < 850)
purrr::keep(num_list,~!(is.numeric(.x) & .x > 750 & .x < 850))
```

---

If you **have** to use a `for` loop, here is one way

```
index <- numeric()
for(i in seq_along(num_list)) {
   if(is.numeric(num_list[[i]]) & num_list[[i]] > 750 & num_list[[i]] < 850)
    index <- c(index, i)
}
num_list[index] <- NULL
```

**data**

```
num_list = list(20000,45,443,"Texas",680,410,"Chennai",121,799,190,810)
```

Comment: @Naats added an option with `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `for` loop, then this is one solution, where you can set undesired part to `NA`, and get rid of them via `!is.na(x)`.

There are some syntax errors in your posted `for` loop code. I made minimal modification to keep the main part of your code, but I added one more line after the `for` loop to reach your goal.

```
for (i in seq(x)){
  if(x[[i]]>750 & x[[i]]<850){
    x[[i]] <- NA
  }
}
x <- x[!is.na(x)]
```

which gives

```
> x
[[1]]
[1] 20000

[[2]]
[1] 45

[[3]]
[1] 443

[[4]]
[1] "Texas"

[[5]]
[1] 680

[[6]]
[1] 410

[[7]]
[1] "Chennai"

[[8]]
[1] 121

[[9]]
[1] 190
```

If you want to add `5` to the the values between `750` and `850`
then you can use

```
x = list(20000,45,443,"Texas",680,410,"Chennai",121,799,190,810) 
for (i in seq(x)){
  if(x[[i]]>750 & x[[i]]<850){
    x[[i]] <- x[[i]] + 5
  }
}
```

such that

```
> x
[[1]]
[1] 20000

[[2]]
[1] 45

[[3]]
[1] 443

[[4]]
[1] "Texas"

[[5]]
[1] 680

[[6]]
[1] 410

[[7]]
[1] "Chennai"

[[8]]
[1] 121

[[9]]
[1] 804

[[10]]
[1] 190

[[11]]
[1] 815
```

Comment: instead of deleting the value what if we want to add 5 @Thomasls Coding

Comment: @Naats do you mean adding 5 to values between 750 and 850 or replace those values by 5? For the former case, `if(x[[i]]>750 & x[[i]]<850){
    x[[i]] <- x[[i]] + 5}`, for the latter case, `if(x[[i]]>750 & x[[i]]<850){
    x[[i]] <- 5}`

Comment: its showing like subscript out of bounds................. adding means if 750 then value should be 755 like that  @ThomaslsCoding

Comment: @Naats I added a new example in my answer regarding adding `5`, you will see it works fine

Comment: nice it works..... what if we want to replace string as 0 @ThomaslsCoding

Comment: @Naats you mean numeric `0` or character `"0"`? You can try `for (i in seq(x)){
  if(is.character(x[[i]])){
    x[[i]] <- 0
  }
}` for numeric or `for (i in seq(x)){
  if(is.character(x[[i]])){
    x[[i]] <- "0"
  }
}` for character

Comment: how to write these condition in lapply function @thomaslsCoading

Comment: @Naats `lapply(x,function(v) ifelse(is.character(v),0,v))`

Comment: sorry ThomaslsCoading not this one first one deleting  if the condition mets 750 & x < 850 using lapply

Comment: @Naats `z <- lapply(x,function(v) ifelse(v>750 & v <850,NA,v)); x <- z[!is.na(z)]`

Comment: instead of na can we delete in ifelse itself....is it possible @thomoslsCoding

Comment: @Naats try `x<-Filter(length,lapply(x,function(v) if(v>750 & v <850) NULL else v))`, it can remove values between 750 and 850

Comment: @Naats `lapply` works well for me. Maybe you need to clean the global environment before you run code each time, otherwise your input if from somewhere else

Comment: this is cool..... do u have any alternate ideas @ThomaslsCoding

Comment: @Naats I have no other ideas

Comment: @Naats Welcome! If you would like to accept my answer, you can click the `check` icon under the voting option, then your question will be marked as `answered` in SO system

Comment: ok @ThomaslsCoding but ihave one doubt here y we r using seq any particular reason is there

Comment: @Naats `seq(n)` generate a sequence from `1` to `n`, otherwise you only have one single value `n` passed to `sapply()`

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- list(20000,45,443,"Texas",680,410,"Chennai",121,799,190,810)
newx <- list()
for (i in x){
  if (is.numeric(i) & (i < 750 | i > 850)){
    print(i)
    newx <- c(newx,i)
  }
}
newx
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sapply` to do this

```
x[!sapply(x, function(x) (is.numeric(x) && x > 750 & x < 850))]
#[[1]]
#[1] 20000

#[[2]]
#[1] 45

#[[3]]
#[1] 443

#[[4]]
#[1] "Texas"

#[[5]]
#[1] 680

#[[6]]
#[1] 410

#[[7]]
#[1] "Chennai"

#[[8]]
#[1] 121

#[[9]]
#[1] 190
```

---

Or using `lapply`, where we loop  through the `list`, check first if it is a `numeric` class and only if then check the number is between 750 and 850, to create a `list` of logical vectors, which we `unlist` to a `vector`, negate (`!`) to change `TRUE/FALSE` to `FALSE/TRUE` and use that to subset the list

```
x[!unlist(lapply(x, function(x) is.numeric(x) && ( x > 750 & x < 850)))]
```

Or do the `unlist` first (as the `list` elements are all of `length` 1), convert to numeric, and create a logical index

```
v1 <- as.numeric(unlist(x))
x[!is.na(v1) & !between(v1, 750, 850)]
```

---

Or with `map`

```
library(purrr)
x[map_lgl(x, ~ is.numeric(.x) && between(.x, 759, 850))]
```

Or using `discard` and `between`

```
discard(x, ~ is.numeric(.x) && between(.x, 750, 850))
```

---

Or an option with `for` loop.  Here, we create an empty `list` ('y'), loop  over the sequence of 'x' and if the condition is not matching in `if`, then concatenate the `list` element to 'y'  and update it by assigning (`<-`)

```
y <- list()
for(i in seq_along(x)) {
   if(!(is.numeric(x[[i]]) && (x[[i]] > 750 & x[[i]] < 850))){
       y <- c(y, x[[i]])
 }
```

Comment: what about lapply @akrun

Comment: @Naats added an option with `for` loop

Comment: its ok @akrun want to solve this code in two ways one is for loop and another one is lapply

Comment: @Naats Please check my  last option with `for` loop

Comment: @Naats Updated with `for` loop and `lapply`

Comment: i got a answer @akrun but the problem is its so confusing to understand...... can u write a code as simplest u can if it is possible

Comment: @Naats I added some description.  Hope it helps

Comment: instead of deleting the value what if we want to add 5 @akrun like if the value between 750 to 800 add 5